# Backbone history back with silent = true

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, history

I want to back history one step without triggering history back. Now I can replace current URL with `router.navigate('#user', {trigger:false, replace: true}`. Is there any way to back history in Backbone without triggering back event? I can use history.back(), but it triggers this event (which forces Backbone to navigate this URL).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found good solution of this problem. But there is one a little bit dirty:

```
var silentBack = function(){
  Backbone.history.stop();
  window.history.back();
  _.defer(function(){Backbone.history.start({silent: true});});
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working. But I'm not sure I can use it in production code, because `Disable Backbone.history, perhaps temporarily. Not useful in a real app, but possibly useful for unit testing Routers.` is written in backbone.js about `stop` method.